# How to use large prompt for GPT-3 models in python?

Tags: python, gpt-3

I am going to extract information from docx file using OpenAI GPT-3 model in python.
But the total length of prompts is too big than GPT-3 provided.

If you have any opinion about this problem, please help me.
Thanks

I tried it to split several chunks, but it is not useful.
Because I need whole information of chunks, not each chunks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [embeddings](https://platform.openai.com/docs/guides/embeddings/what-are-embeddings) to find the most relevant pieces of information to build an answer. Here is a good example of using it in a similar case: [Question answering using embeddings-based search](https://github.com/openai/openai-cookbook/blob/7d418b9bf2b5546b2e8e2e3e2a1813ec5d939540/examples/Question_answering_using_embeddings.ipynb)

Comment: I mean I am trying to find a way to send large prompts to GPT-3 models in python.